# The action 'redirect_callbacks' could not be found for Users::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I have a problem with omniauth and devise_token_auth. When i try to register an user with facebook, the callback not working.

Her's my **Gemfile** :

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2'
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
       scope :v1 do
         mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
         match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]
      end
  end
  root to:'welcomes#index'
end
```

Here's the **app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, "XXX", "XXX",
  :scope => 'public_profile,email,user_birthday',
  :info_fields => 'id,about,birthday,email,first_name,gender,last_name'
end
```

And finally, this is the console response :

```
Started GET "/api/v1/auth/facebook" for 192.168.33.1 at 2016-05-14 10:26:00 +0000
Cannot render console from 192.168.33.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255


Started GET "/omniauth/facebook?resource_class=User" for 192.168.33.1 at 2016-05-14 10:26:00 +0000
Cannot render console from 192.168.33.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
I, [2016-05-14T10:26:00.995076 #3226]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/omniauth/facebook/callback?code=XXX" for 192.168.33.1 at 2016-05-14 10:26:01 +0000
Cannot render console from 192.168.33.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
I, [2016-05-14T10:26:01.130357 #3226]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'redirect_callbacks' could not be found for Users::OmniauthCallbacksController):
```

Am I missing something simple? I've been searching for a solution for the last few day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `OmniauthCallbacksController`.

One way is to inherit the controller from `DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController` and hooked into the actions:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def redirect_callbacks
      super 
      # some logic here
    end
end
```

Other way is to copy the whole controller [code](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb) from the [`devise_token_auth`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem and work around them:

```
module DeviseTokenAuth
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController

    attr_reader :auth_params
    skip_before_action :set_user_by_token, raise: false
    skip_after_action :update_auth_header

    # intermediary route for successful omniauth authentication. omniauth does
    # not support multiple models, so we must resort to this terrible hack.
    def redirect_callbacks

      # derive target redirect route from 'resource_class' param, which was set
      # before authentication.
      devise_mapping = [request.env['omniauth.params']['namespace_name'],
                        request.env['omniauth.params']['resource_class'].underscore.gsub('/', '_')].compact.join('_')
      redirect_route = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/#{Devise.mappings[devise_mapping.to_sym].fullpath}/#{params[:provider]}/callback"

      # preserve omniauth info for success route. ignore 'extra' in twitter
      # auth response to avoid CookieOverflow.
      session['dta.omniauth.auth'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra')
      session['dta.omniauth.params'] = request.env['omniauth.params']

      redirect_to redirect_route
    end

    # some code here

  end
end
```